# couchbase view using multiple keys to get result

Tags: mapreduce, couchbase, couchbase-view

I have the following document

```
{

   "Credit_Amount": 99,
   "Acc_no": 138,
   "Job_No": "esmwga",
   "Source_No": "x",
   "Temp": 1017,
   "Document_No": "gaf",
   "Debit_Amount": 67,
   "User_Id": "xirbzsewiw"
}
```

and my map function is this

```
function (doc, meta) {
    if(doc.Type == "GLEntry")
    {
      emit([doc.Acc_no,doc.User_Id],[doc.Credit_Amount,doc.Debit_Amount]);
    }
}
```

and this is my reduce function

```
function(key,values,rereduce){
  var sum1=0,sum2=0;
  for(var i=0;i<values.length;++i)
  {
    sum1+=values[i][0];
    sum2+=values[i][1];
  }
  return ([sum1,sum2])
    }
```

when I pass this key

```
[138,"xirbzsewiw"]
group level 2
```

I get this output

```
[ 99, 67 ]
```

But When I give this as key

```
[138]
group level 1
```

I get empty result. But what I have understood is it will group using only acc number when I give group level 1 so it should give same output. Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Abhi is correct, the result set for your specified key is empty so the reduce is also empty. You can check that by querying with `reduce=false`.

You are probably confused from another question you asked where you are using `startkey` and `endkey` to get a range. With `startkey` and `endkey` you do not need to specify exact keys, the first partial match will be treated as the start or end. In your example if you query with `startkey=[138]&endkey=[139]&inclusive_end=false` you should see the result you expect.

Comment: so there is no partial match in `key` and `keys` parameter? only `startkey` and `endkey` has partial match?

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I think is probably happening here:

- Your map function emits keys like: [138,"xirbzsewiw"]
- You need to pass key that your map function generates as "keys" while doing reduce operations. In 2nd case, you're passing [138], which isn't a legitimate key so it isn't matching anything in index and hence you aren't seeing any output.

`group_level` does filtering on **output** i.e. numbers of indexes upto which you want to get from an array of strings. You might want to look at [understanding group level view queries](http://blog.couchbase.com/understanding-grouplevel-view-queries-compound-keys), if you haven't already to have better understanding of `group_level`

Comment: So there is no way I can ignore some right hand key values in emit function? I think I read somewhere that we can skip some of the right hand values but all left hand values should be provided.